Is there a login issue with Jaspersoft Studio?
Attempting to create my account and login to Jaspersoft Studio Community 7.0.1 for the first time today. I am unable to get past the login screen even with the QR code option to login. The error I receive when attempting to login is below. I am unable to find any information online about this specific error, and I have not been able to login since yesterday. I've attempted to downgrade to 6.21.3 and reset my password twice. I'm able to login to the community forums just fine.
java.lang.Exception: Login not available at this time
at com.jaspersoft.studio.statistics.heartbeat.CommunityLogin.getCsrf(CommunityLogin.java:58)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.statistics.heartbeat.CommunityLogin.verifyCredentials(CommunityLogin.java:106)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.statistics.heartbeat.CommunityLoginDialog.buttonPressed(CommunityLoginDialog.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4274)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4072)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.rcp.intro.Application.start(Application.java:96)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:651)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:588)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1459)


Resolved from the Jaspersoft community forums; staff has responded that this is an ongoing login issue that others are facing.

Hi Erica.
The login issue is the same as described in other posts. Some of them contains screenshot images with the same error as yours.
Investigation is in progress internally. Sorry for the inconvenience.
Best regards,
Massimo.

